# Linker error scrolling past too quickly

Tags: command-line, cmake

I'm building a project with CMake. I'm able to build everything, but am getting a lengthy linker error.

I've tried piping `make` to `less`, but doing that I only get two screens, one that shows the build progress and one that shows the truncated linker error. How can I slow down the linker error scroll rate or otherwise get access to it?

I also tried

```
make > buildinfo.txt
```

but again that only showed me the build progress. There wasn't anything in there about the linker error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are being shown on STDERR (file descriptor 2), not STDOUT (file descriptor 1); as you are redirecting/piping the STDOUT only, you won't get hold of the STDERR contents. So you need some way to handle the STDERR.

---

If you want to save the STDOUT and STDERR both in a file:

```
make &>buildinfo.txt
```

POSIX-ly:

```
make >buildinfo.txt 2>&1
```

Only the STDERR:

```
make 2>buildinfo.txt
```

the above will print STDOUT on the terminal (assuming FD 1 is attached to the terminal), if you do not want that, discard it:

```
make >/dev/null 2>buildinfo.txt
```

---

Now, for piping the STDOUT and STDERR to some other commands STDIN via `pipefs` (`|`), e.g to `less`:

```
make |& less
```

POSIX-ly:

```
make 2>&1 | less
```

Only the STDERR:

```
make 2>&1 >/dev/null | less
```

Comment: Am I correct as to why the last command works: `2>&1` redirects `2` to where `1` points to **at the moment** (i.e. STDOUT), afterwards `1` can be redirected to `dev/null`but that doesn't influence the redirection of `2` ?

Comment: @guntbert Spot on :)